# Cauchy's Theorem for Abelian Groups from Herstein's Topics in Algebra $2^{\text{nd}}$ ed.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

[image: App 1]

I do not understand the third to last line: "Combining this with $\dots$".

How does Herstein conclude that $b \in N$?

I am seeing that $(Nb)^{o(N)} = (Nb)^p$, but I don't see how this says $b \in N$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $(Nb)^p=N$, and $p$ is prime, the order of $Nb$ must be either $1$ or $p$. Since $(Nb)^{o(N)}=N$, the order of $Nb$ must divide $o(N)$. But $p\nmid o(N)$, so the order of $Nb$ cannot be $p$ and therefore must be $1$, meaning that $Nb=N$.

Comment: Doesn't get more to the point then that. BTW, this brings me back to my Math 337 Honors Algebra course, where I fell in love with 2 things: abstract algebra and Herstein's classic text.

Answer (score 1):

Let $k$ be the order of $Nb$. Since $(Nb)^{o(N)}=N$ and $(Nb)^p=N$ it follows that $k | o(N)$ and $k|p$.

So, $k|gcd(o(N),p)=1$, since $p$ does not divide $o(N)$. Therefore $(Nb)^k=Nb^k=N$ becomes $Nb^1=N$, so $Nb=Ne$. By the coset equality lemma, this holds if and only if $be^{-1}=be=b \in N$.